# \href command of package hyperref does not work as it should

Tags: packages, hyperlink, href

I am unaware of what could make \href fail so I will place here my code together with all packages used. I've seen in the past packages intercept one another.

I am trying to produce a link to a paper like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, draft]{book}

% Packages
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
[\href{https://pos.sissa.it/397/174/}{doi: 10.22323/1.397.0174}]
\end{document}
```

However the output is not clickable in my PDF:
[image]

I can use \href in my CV just fine, which is of course another document class. Has anybody seen this before?

Comment: Sorry but is it not a good question if you show lots of unrelated packages but leave out a small but complete document body which would give one the chance to actually test your issue. Apart from this: remove the draft option in the class.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I've updated the post. Removing draft did fix my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Ulrike's input, the issue was the "draft" setting in the document class